# LocalStorage pierde datos al refrescar la pagina

Tags: javascript

Cada vez que refresco la pagina pierdo los datos del localStorage, entiendo por el codigo que los almacena pero no se porque los pierde, ayuda, muchas gracias.

```
const ganarJuego = () =>{
    if(contadorC.length==2){
      alert("Ganaste en " + cronometro + " secs");
      document.getElementById("cronometro").innerHTML = "";
      let name = prompt("Introduce tu nombre");
      arrayGanadores.push({
        nombre: name,
        tiempo: cronometro
      });
      inicial = JSON.stringify(arrayGanadores);
      localStorage.setItem("aG", inicial);
      let listaG = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("aG"));
      document.getElementById("listaGanadores").innerHTML = mostrarGanadores(listaG);
      clearInterval(segundo);
      cronometro=0;
      cronometroClick = true;
    }
  }

  const mostrarGanadores = (listaG) =>{
    let lista="";
  for(let i=0; i<listaG.length; i++){
     lista += `${listaG[i].nombre}: ${listaG[i].tiempo} segundos<br>`
    }
    return lista;
  }
```

Comment: seria bueno que hagas un console.log() y muestres lo que sale

Comment: ¿Cual es el valor inicial de `arrayGanadores`?

Comment: No se pierden los valores, lo que pasa es que tienes que mandar a llamar tu función **mostrarGanadores()** cuando inicia tu aplicacion, por lo que puedo ver en tu código listas a los ganadores solo cuando ganan, pero cuando inicia tu aplicación??

Comment: He observado un poco el código y lo que encontré es que no se comprueba si existe algo en `localStorage`. Lo que ocurre es que se inserta directamente el valor generado por las instrucciones escritas en la función antes de recuperarse. Primero, se debe comprobar, luego recuperar y _parsear_  a JSON, actualizarlo cuando sea necesario y recuperarlo nuevamente cuando se necesite.

Comment: Para resumir un poco, estás sobrescribiendo primero antes de recuperar el valor existente, si lo hay.

Comment: Daniel, recuerda colocar acá [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Es decir, el código HTML faltante, las variables que estás utilizando en la función que has compartido, pero que no has definido acá para que puedas aumentar tus posibilidades de conseguir ayuda. Por otra parte, puedes realizar un [tour] para que conozcas cómo funciona este sitio Web y ganes tu primera medalla.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. como hago para recuperarlo cuando lo necesite?

Comment: Ya tengo una respuesta que lo explica, pero, hace falta que coloques la parte faltante de lo que tienes para reproducirlo allí y tener más contexto para completar la explicación. Sin embargo, se deja una pista en el siguiente comentario.

Comment: Primero debes  utilizar en `localStorage` el método `getItrm` antes que `setItem` y luego verificar si existe para enviar los datos obtenidos, _si los hay_ al array antes de actualizarlo para posteriormente enviarlo a `localStorage` cuando necesites actualizarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Solo necesitas leer lo que haya guardado en *localStorage* al cargar la página, asignándolo a una variable que irás actualizando conforme avance el juego y guardando cuando sea necesario.

Revisa los comentarios y no dudes en preguntar si algo no quedó claro.

```
// Definir la lista de ganadores como variable global
let listaG;
// Cargar desde localStorage solo 1 vez, al cargar la página
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // Cargar desde localStorage o inicializar como arreglo vacío
    listaG = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("aG")) || [];
});

const ganarJuego = () => {
    if(contadorC.length==2) {
      alert("Ganaste en " + cronometro + " secs");
      document.getElementById("cronometro").innerHTML = "";
      let name = prompt("Introduce tu nombre");
      // Utiliza siempre la misma variable, no necesitas crear otras
      listaG.push({
        nombre: name,
        tiempo: cronometro
      });
      // Guarda los datos en localStorage
      localStorage.setItem("aG", JSON.stringify(listaG));

      // No necesitas volver a cargar, porque la lista se actualizó
      // Tampoco necesitas enviarla por parámetro al crear el HTML
      document.getElementById("listaGanadores").innerHTML = mostrarGanadores();
      clearInterval(segundo);
      cronometro=0;
      cronometroClick = true;
    }
}

// La función no recibe parámetro, también usa la variable global
const mostrarGanadores = () =>{
    let lista="";
    for(let i=0; i<listaG.length; i++){
        lista += `${listaG[i].nombre}: ${listaG[i].tiempo} segundos<br>`
    }
    return lista;
}
```